# How can I combine the "paste" command with the "ifelse" command in a for loop with R?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, paste

## For Loop in R including paste and ifelse

Dear Community,

I'm trying to combine a `paste` command in combination with an `ifelse` command in a for loop with R Studio - but I'm receiving the error message **Error: Unexpected '}' in "}"**.

### Download simplified Dataset:

I have created a simple dataset to illustrate my problem. You can download via the following link:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/jxvcfvxnv7pf8e74tulzq/Data.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=de7b3e2d0ge8ju6tsvz2bkzuv

### Background:

I would like evaluate empirical data from a test. Therefore I need to create a new column (called Point.[i]) for every item (i = 1-4). If the value in the "Answer.[i]"-column corresponds to the value of the  "Right.Answer.[i]"-column, I would like to give 1 point (otherwise 0 points) for that task.

### My Code

This is easy for one column:

```
data1 <- mutate(data, Point.1 = ifelse(Answer.1 == Right.Answer.1, 1, 0))
```

Now I would like write a for loop doing this for all columns, but the following code is not working:

```
for (i in 1:4) {
  data[i] <- mutate(data, paste("Answer.",i) = ifelse(paste("Answer.",i) == paste("Answer.",i), 1, 0))
  print(data)
}
```

I would be very grateful for any advice. Thanks in advance!

Karla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
for (i in 1:3) {
  var <- sym(paste0("Answer.",i))
  var2 <- sym(paste0("Right.Answer.",i))
  data <- data %>%  mutate(!!var := ifelse(!!var == !!var2, 1, 0))
  print(data)
}
```

Output:

```
data
  Person Answer.1 Right.Answer.1 Answer.2 Right.Answer.2 Answer.3 Right.Answer.3
1      1        1              A        1              B        0              B
2      2        0              A        0              B        1              B
3      3        1              A        0              B        1              B
```

Comment: Hello Duck, thanks a lot for your fast and helpful respond. Your solution works out very well! This was my first post on stack overflow and I'm very impressed. Have a happy new year!

Comment: @Karla Always a pleasure helping!